not able to use router-outlet in angular version 18
The problem I am facing is that the router-outlet element is not recognized in your Angular application, leading to the error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element. Despite importing and using RouterModule correctly, the issue persists.
my app.module.ts file is below
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { MatBadgeModule } from "@angular/material/badge";
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
import { MatIconModule } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { MatProgressBarModule } from "@angular/material/progress-bar";
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";
import { MatTooltipModule } from "@angular/material/tooltip";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterModule, RouterOutlet } from "@angular/router";
import { ToastrModule } from "ngx-toastr";
import { DashboardComponent } from "./__framework/layout/dashboard/dashboard.component";
import { ProfileMenuModule } from "./__framework/layout/dashboard/profile-menu/profile-menu.module";
import { SidemenuModule } from "./__framework/layout/dashboard/sidemenu/sidemenu.module";
import { Layout1Component } from "./__framework/layout/layout1/layout1.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { LoginModule } from "./modules/auth/login/login.module";
import { SharedModule } from "./shared/shared.module";
import { ɵBrowserAnimationBuilder } from "@angular/animations";


const DashboardLayoutModules = [
  SidemenuModule,
  ProfileMenuModule
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Layout1Component,
    DashboardComponent


  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LoginModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule,
    RouterOutlet,
    MatTooltipModule,
    CommonModule,



  ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }





my app.routing.module.ts file is given below

import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Layout1Component } from './__framework/layout/layout1/layout1.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './__framework/layout/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { Routes, ExtraOptions, PreloadAllModules, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},
  {
    path: '',
    component: Layout1Component,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
      },

    ]
  },
  // {
  //  // path: 'app.dashboard',
  //  path: '',
  // //  canActivate:[AuthGuard],
  // //   canActivateChild:[AuthGuard],
  //    component: DashboardComponent,
  //   //loadChildren: () => import('./modules/auth/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
  //   children: [
  //     {
  //       // path: '',
  //       // loadChildren: () => import('./modules/admin/pages/dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule)
  //     },
  //   ]
  // },

];
const routerConfig: ExtraOptions = {
  scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
  useHash: true,
  preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
};
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerConfig)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}


My app.component.ts file is 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',

  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}



My app.component.html file is 


<router-outlet></router-outlet>


after compiling it , i keep on getting the error
Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

3 
i am using latest angular version 18


In your app.config.ts in the providers array you should add
provideRouter(
  routes
),

